# Why is my ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 using RC relative references is printing the wrong value?

Tags: excel, vba, row

Basically here's the snippet that doesn't work:

```
Range("AL2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[" + CStr(3814 - 30) + "]C[-9]:R[" + CStr(3814) + "]C[-9])"
```

I would expect cell AL2 to read : "=AVERAGE(AC3784:**AC3814**)" but instead it reads "=AVERAGE(AC3786:**AC3816**)"

Why are the numbers 2 larger than I expected? Does it have to do with the selected range being row 2?

Comment: by using the `[]` you are using relative references which mean the row will be `3814` rows below where it is being placed or `2+3814` which is `3816`  the first row with those number should be `3786` for the same reason.

Comment: if you want it absolute then remove the `[]` and it will use the number provided as the absolute reference.